How to fix .NET MAUI Blazor Hybrid app code object is not signed at all issue in Mac M2 when Building for iOS?
I created .NET MAUI application for ERP purpose. currently it deploying to android and windows as well and those are working fine. we started it from .NET 7 and currently we are using .NET 8 as well.
here is description of my environment. for iOS I tried to build using iOS using XCode latest and dotnet 8 for mac arm64 devices and apple m2 MacBook as well. but I cannot directly connect my MacBook and windows pc. there are too much lessons for develop by connecting windows and MacBook.
I tried to build it from MacBook itself. it seems working but I got error below. I need to fix that but I couldn't find any way to fix that.
   

/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk/17.2.8078/tools/msbuild/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(2257,3): error : /usr/bin/codesign exited with code 1: [<Project_path>/bluelotus360.com.mauiBlazor.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios] 

/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk/17.2.8078/tools/msbuild/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(2257,3): error : <Project_path>/bin/Release/net8.0-ios/ios-arm64/bluelotus360.com.mauiBlazor.app: code object is not signed at all [<Project_path>/bluelotus360.com.mauiBlazor.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios] 

/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk/17.2.8078/tools/msbuild/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(2257,3): error : In subcomponent: <Project_path>/bin/Release/net8.0-ios/ios-arm64/bluelotus360.com.mauiBlazor.app/System.Xml.Linq.dll [<Project_path>/bluelotus360.com.mauiBlazor.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios] 

/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk/17.2.8078/tools/msbuild/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(2257,3): error : Failed to codesign '<Project_path>/bin/Release/net8.0-ios/ios-arm64/bluelotus360.com.mauiBlazor.app': <Project_path>/bin/Release/net8.0-ios/ios-arm64/bluelotus360.com.mauiBlazor.app: code object is not signed at all [<Project_path>/bluelotus360.com.mauiBlazor.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios] 

/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk/17.2.8078/tools/msbuild/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(2257,3): error : In subcomponent: <Project_path>/bin/Release/net8.0-ios/ios-arm64/bluelotus360.com.mauiBlazor.app/System.Xml.Linq.dll [<Project_path>/bluelotus360.com.mauiBlazor.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios] 

/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk/17.2.8078/tools/msbuild/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(2257,3): error :  [<Project_path>/bluelotus360.com.mauiBlazor.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios] 

/usr/local/share/dotnet/packs/Microsoft.iOS.Sdk/17.2.8078/tools/msbuild/iOS/Xamarin.Shared.targets(2257,3): error :          [<Project_path>/bluelotus360.com.mauiBlazor.csproj::TargetFramework=net8.0-ios] 



here is terminal code I used
dotnet publish -f net8.0-ios -c Release

There is a guide to verify certificate taken from apple.
Blog Post I used
then it shows as verified certificate in keychain.
are there any other workaround?

The error message indicates that there are something wrong with the code sign. Have you added any iOS capabilities? And do you add some entitlement key (refer to iOS entitlements)? If so, you should create provisioning profile manually.

I create provision profile and import to xcode. I didnt use any extra permission yet for that app.

From the docs: Publish a .NET MAUI app, you must have a Mac and an Apple Developer Program to create an App Store distribution provisioning profile.

Create a distribution certificate: Create a
distribution certificate.

Create an App ID: Create an App ID.

Create a provisioning profile: Create a
provisioning profile.


For more information, please refer to Publish a .NET MAUI iOS app for App Store distribution - .NET MAUI | Microsoft Learn and Publish an iOS app using the command line.

I obtain all of that things and I configured that things also.

please open your MAUI project by VS for Mac and check that you can select the provisioning profile and make sure the certificate and provisioning profile exist on your local Mac. And you can also try to publish the app via VS for Mac directly: right-click the project->Archive for Publishing -> select the archive->Sign and Distribute->Appstore->Export->select provisioning profile. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/publish-app-store?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=vsmac#publish-the-app

now visual studio for mac is retired. I used visual studio code and .NET MAUI Archive extension for it. error is same. so I tried to sign .app (this generates as intermediate step in bin > net8.0-ios > ios-arm64 folder) bundle manually using codesign same error happened. so I use codesign with --deep  parameter in terminal. it seems work fine. but it generates .app app only how can I create .ipa file for publish ios?


You can try to open the app in Xcode and then open Window --> Organizer to see if there's .ipa file there. 2. Note that Visual Studio for Mac is scheduled for retirement by August 31 2024, so you can still use it for publishing.


I clean all iOS Related configurations from that project and then given appstore admin permission for mac user's app ID and did all the certification creations and provision profille creations from that user. then it works fine. thanks all.

@Gayantha Thanks for the update, glad it works well.:)
